# I want to display a gradient over a gradient in css

Tags: css, display, linear-gradients

I want a gradient that have 30% black and 70% transparent and it has to be over my container's gradient and under my ul

i want this black gradient over my animated gradient and under my ul. so, this gradient has to create a blur effect under my ul so it mostly cover my white text and also it has to be **90 deg**

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 8fr;
  background: linear- gradient(45deg, rgb(0, 0, 255), rgb(150, 150, 255), rgb(255, 150, 150), rgb(255, 0, 0));
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: 300% 300%;
  animation: color 12s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}

li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 4rem;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul:hover li a {
  filter: blur(2px);
  color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
}

ul li a:hover {
  filter: blur(0);
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.2rem;
  animation: revealtext 3s;
}

@keyframes revealtext {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(30px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li a::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: .1em;
  left: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-107%);
  transition: transform 2s;
}

li:hover a:before {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You appear to have a typo (a space) in your `background: linear- gradient` declaration; this may - or may not - be relevant to your problem, can you clarify?

Comment: It's not.you can see my problem at the top.

Comment: Then please correct the code and ensure it works correctly to reproduce your problem; having *extra* errors just complicates the attempts to try and help you. Incidentally, you say "I want," and "it has to be..." where did you get stuck, what specific problem are you having?

Comment: Ohhh ok sorry about that I get it. I will post this question again thanks for your concern I really appreciate it, again I am really sorry for this inconvenience.

Comment: No problem, and as for the question all you have to do, realistically, is edit the question to improve it.